# create function unterminated dollar-quoted string

Tags: postgresql, go, libpq, goose

I'm trying to create this function with [Goose](https://bitbucket.org/liamstask/goose) using a postgres ([pq lib](https://github.com/lib/pq)) database.

My code is as follows:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_userlocation(user_id INT, location_id INT) RETURNS VOID AS
   $BODY$
   BEGIN
       LOOP
           UPDATE userslocations SET count = count+1 WHERE userid = user_id AND locationid = location_id;
        IF found THEN
            RETURN;
        END IF;
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO userslocations(userid,locationid, count) VALUES (user_id, location_id, 1);
               RETURN;
           EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
        END;
       END LOOP;
   END;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I try to `goose up` it provides an error:

```
(pq: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$BODY$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        -- first try to update the key
        UPDATE userslocations SET count = count+1 WHERE userid = user_id AND locationid = location_id;
"), quitting migration.
```

Goose basically echo's the `pq` library error, so I dont think it's in Goose, but rather the pq-library. Query runs succesful on pgAdmin III.

Comment: If you paste the function definition directly into psql, does it work?

Comment: Yes, I used the Query window in pgAdmin III, where I pasted the code and executed it. It worked and I can use it with my go-app/pq lib (`exec("Select add_userlocation(1,1)")`)

Comment: That implies goose must be modifying the text before passing it to libpq. Does it do any interpretation of input strings?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the [goose documentation](https://github.com/pressly/goose#sql-migrations), complex statements that include semicolons must be annotated with `-- +goose StatementBegin` and `-- +goose StatementEnd`

Your statement contains semicolons embedded within it so you need to use these annotations. Otherwise goose mangles the SQL so that libpq gives errors.

Comment: You saved me with your answer :-)